# gdb simulator crash after "target sim" "sim memory-size 4Mb" "load" "run"

Tags: debugging, gdb, target, ebpf

My plan to debug eBPF code using the latest gdb support. however the simulator crash after I run . so i tried regular "hello world" c code compiled with -g option (gcc -g hello_wold.c) got the same issue.

gdb version : GNU gdb (GDB) 12.0.50.20211105-git

```
Reading symbols from /root/hello_program/a.out...
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) sim memory-size 4Mb
(gdb) load
Loading section .interp, size 0x1c lma 238
Loading section .note.ABI-tag, size 0x20 lma 254
Loading section .note.gnu.build-id, size 0x24 lma 274
Loading section .gnu.hash, size 0x1c lma 298
Loading section .dynsym, size 0xc0 lma 2b8
Loading section .dynstr, size 0x96 lma 378
Loading section .gnu.version, size 0x10 lma 40e
Loading section .gnu.version_r, size 0x20 lma 420
Loading section .rela.dyn, size 0xd8 lma 440
Loading section .rela.plt, size 0x18 lma 518
Loading section .init, size 0x17 lma 530
Loading section .plt, size 0x20 lma 550
Loading section .plt.got, size 0x8 lma 570
Loading section .text, size 0x1c2 lma 580
Loading section .fini, size 0x9 lma 744
Loading section .rodata, size 0x10 lma 750
Loading section .eh_frame_hdr, size 0x3c lma 760
Loading section .eh_frame, size 0x10c lma 7a0
Loading section .init_array, size 0x8 lma 200dd8
Loading section .fini_array, size 0x8 lma 200de0
Loading section .jcr, size 0x8 lma 200de8
Loading section .dynamic, size 0x1e0 lma 200df0
Loading section .got, size 0x30 lma 200fd0
Loading section .got.plt, size 0x20 lma 201000
Loading section .data, size 0x10 lma 201020
Start address 580
Transfer rate: 17760 bits in <1 sec.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/hello_program/a.out 


Fatal signal: Aborted
----- Backtrace -----
0x55ffda5588a7 gdb_internal_backtrace_1
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/bt-utils.c:121
0x55ffda5588a7 _Z22gdb_internal_backtracev
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/bt-utils.c:164
0x55ffda6506cd handle_fatal_signal
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/event-top.c:896
0x7f89e035905f ???
    /build/glibc-77giwP/glibc-2.24/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
0x7f89e0358fff __GI_raise
    ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
0x7f89e035a429 __GI_abort
    /build/glibc-77giwP/glibc-2.24/stdlib/abort.c:89
0x55ffda8e2728 sim_engine_invalid_insn
    /root/binutils-gdb/sim/bpf/traps.c:37
0x55ffda8da83d execute
    /root/binutils-gdb/sim/bpf/mloop-le.c:119
```

for bpf code i compiled with **( clang -target bpf -g -O2 -c hello_world.c)**

**hello world bpf code**

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int bpf_prog(void *ctx) {
    
    char buf[] = "Hello World!\n";
    bpf_trace_printk(buf, sizeof(buf)); 
    bpf_trace_printk(buf, sizeof(buf)); 
    bpf_trace_printk(buf, sizeof(buf)); 
    bpf_trace_printk(buf, sizeof(buf));
            
    return 0;

}
```

**Error**

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /root/ebpf_test/hello_world.o...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/ebpf_test/hello_world.o)
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) sim memory-size 4Mb
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0x28 lma 0
Loading section .rodata.str1.1, size 0xd lma 0
Start address 0
Transfer rate: 424 bits in <1 sec.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/ebpf_test/hello_world.o 


Fatal signal: Aborted
----- Backtrace -----
0x562154f4a63b gdb_internal_backtrace_1
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/bt-utils.c:121
0x562154f4a63b _Z22gdb_internal_backtracev
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/bt-utils.c:164
0x56215504d2ba handle_fatal_signal
    /root/binutils-gdb/gdb/event-top.c:896
0x7f6f1a85503f ???
0x7f6f1a854fb7 ???
0x7f6f1a856920 ???
0x5621552fb9f8 sim_engine_invalid_insn
    /root/binutils-gdb/sim/bpf/traps.c:37
0x5621552f3aaa execute
    /root/binutils-gdb/sim/bpf/mloop-le.c:119
0x5621552f3aaa bpfbf_ebpfle_engine_run_full
    /root/binutils-gdb/sim/bpf/mloop-le.c:222
0x5621552ddee4 engine_run_1
```

same happen when i try to debug an ebpf program. any help is appreciated to understand where to begin fixing the issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the number of sections that GDB loaded, I don't believe your object file was compiled as eBPF bytecode. Was `gcc -g hello_world.c` the command you used to produce it? This will compile instructions from your host architecture, likely x86_64.

#### Compiling to eBPF

To compile to eBPF instructions instead, most people use clang rather than gcc. There is a gcc backend for eBPF now, but I don't know what its status is, I'm just aware that its eBPF support is not quite as complete as clang/LLVM. **With clang, you can run:**

```
$ clang -target bpf -g -O2 -c hello_world.c
```

This will produce an object file containing eBPF instructions. Note that I'd usually add `-Wall` and `-o hello_world.o` to display potential warnings and to name the output file. The resulting object file should work in gdb, provided you have a recent version with support for eBPF (see [here](https://twitter.com/qeole/status/1291026052953911296) otherwise).

If you care about [a specific eBPF instruction set](https://pchaigno.github.io/bpf/2021/10/20/ebpf-instruction-sets.html) (if you're getting started, you probably don't), you can specify it by compiling in two steps instead, and passing the relevant option via the `-mcpu` option for `llc`:

```
$ clang -g -O2 -Wall -emit-llvm -c hello_world.c -o - | \
    llc -march=bpf -mcpu=probe -filetype=obj -o hello_world.o
```

See also [this resource](https://qmonnet.github.io/whirl-offload/2020/04/12/llvm-ebpf-asm/) for details and compiling into and from assembly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I actually started trying to get it to work after seeing your twitter steps.   if i compile with "-target bpf" gdb says "No debugging symbols found in ...."  removing that option make gdb see the debug symbols.  i tried compiling with lang as you stated and still got the same crash after i do "run"     what is the error exactly saying ? should gdb crash instead of exiting gracefully ? I will edit the original question to add the hello world code

Comment: bpf code and error were added to the original question

Comment: looks like the first issue is why debug symbols are not generated with "-target bpf" option !

Comment: Strange. Debug symbols: You should have them for eBPF too, if you compile with the `-g` option (but it seems you're doing so already). Unless your clang version is too old. What version do you have? Regarding the crash: I don't think that's supposed to happen either :). Maybe worth reporting to the maintainers. On my side, when trying to run your eBPF program (same gdb version and same instructions), I get another error (`core: 2 byte misaligned read to address 0x6f57206fdbc385b7 at 0x`, bug?), but no crash. I can still run some other programs, e.g. a function that just returns 0 passes fine.

Comment: clang version :  clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
                                                                              ..............................                          would it be possible to provide a simple tutorial in case you already have one : bpf sample c code + how to compile + and how to run + how to set breakpoint and print registers or point me to a resource . i m trying to make sure the errors are related to my environment and not gdb (since you already got similar errors)

Comment: on a different machine i got similar errors like yours.  the 2 byte misaligned . and an empty program that return 0 finish with no issues.  however sitting breakpoints didnt work even at the "return 0" line

Comment: clang 6.0 probably lacks support for generating BTF (debug info for eBPF), try with a new version if you can. Newest is best, although I think BTF was supported since 8.0 or something like that (not sure). Sorry I don't have a more detailed tutorial ready at the moment. I experimented a little bit, I think I had breakpoints and step-by-step working with some programs, but that was last year and I haven't kept the materials :/. I'm afraid you'll have to experiment by yourself. Maybe reach out on the relevant mailing lists to ask the developers of the feature and let them know of the crash?

Comment: updating clang to 8.0 didnt fix the symbols issue. thanks so much for the help and the chat .. appreciated .